# Shader vs. Vector Node - not producing any shadows for displaced geometry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, shadows, vector-mapping, shader-nodes

**TL;DR:** Why are shadows showing when rendering displaced geometry with Shader-Nodes but not with Vector-Nodes?

I have created a super simple shader via node setup. I'm using Cycles, and the material has heavy displacement via surface subdivision.

So far, I came up with two ways of doing this:

- Create a diffuse BSDF and set the color accordingly. Note: the last add-shader operation has a green output connector, a "closure".
- Create a RGB color node and directly use it as input for the material surface. Note: for the future, I will have to use a vector here, which also holds 3 RGB values, so it has a purple output connector.

Now, with approach 1, the shadows are rendered correctly. With approach 2, however, there are no shadows and the entire material is colored in the set RGB color. This is no surprise, as the RGB color directly is applied to the material surface.

I know that I could simply put the RGB color as input for the diffuse BSDF and get a colored image with shadows. BUT: this is just a sample MWE, later I will need to do advanced shading calculations and use the resulting vectors as color values. So I was hoping that there is some way to actually make the displaced geometry create shadows?

Alternatively: How can I convert the vector output to a shader output, i.e., vector -> closure, without any additional shading calculations? In short: is there an "identity shader", that takes a color as input, and outputs a color image with shadows? Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]
I have attached an image and the MWE blend file:

[image]

Comment: Images would be useful for users who may answer when asking material questions. Please [edit] your question and add images of the shader nodes you are using, as well as the results to help demonstrate the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks @Timaroberts, I have edited the question accordingly.